# Add description for Field Group

Tags: 7, entities

I am using the [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module on my user registration form.

Is there any option to add a help text (description) to the whole group, which has 7 input fields?

I want the users to be able to see some description text below the FieldGroup heading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Content type > Manage fileds > Field Group`.

In the filed group you can find settings icon beside.

[image]

Clicking on that will give you a field to add description to.

[image]

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't showing on user registration form

Comment: actually my fielgroup is `div` not `fieldset`

Comment: @RaheelKhan Can't you change it to fieldset?

Comment: No :( It is looking odd if i do it to fieldset here is how it look in div and i want it in this way ..See my updated question attachment

Comment: @RaheelKhan BTW I've tried it for `div` . I could able to see the description field.

Comment: oh sorry its working :D because of font color i wasn't seeing it :D Thanks alot.

Comment: @RaheelKhan :) Great! I am just about to post my latest screenshot. Anyway I'll update that too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Some field_group formatters do have a description setting, others do not.

If you look at field_group_field_group_formatter_info(), and look at 'instance_settings' for each entry, you see which settings are available for each formatter.

From what I tried, after changing the formatter for a field group, the new settings only appear after saving the entire field_ui form.